# How to make Internet Download Manager (IDM) understand unicode character from command line argument

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net program which send request to add file to IDM queue through API. Everything work fine, except if my filename contains unicode characters, IDM will get those characters as ? symbol. I want to know how to make the right call to the API so IDM will work correctly with unicode character.

My code is :

```
Dim r As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\DownloadManager")
Dim fileName as string = "unicode-únìcodeỵư"
Dim p As New Process()
p.StartInfo.FileName = r.GetValue("ExePath")
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/d """+downloadLink+""" /a /n /p ""E:\\"" /f """ + fileName + """"
p.Start()
```

Comment: The release notes for IDM say that Unicode support for filenames was added in version 5.18 beta (Released: Aug 10, 2009). Which version are you using?

Comment: I use latest version 6.23. I know if i use idm to capture link on site such as youtube, it recognized the correct unicode name, but when i use command line it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

simply declare a function to encrypt URL(filename,download link) to Base64 encode then use return of function in :

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/d """+downloadLink+""" /a /n /p ""E:\\"" /f """ + fileName + """"
```

Comment: It doesn't work, if i use base64 IDM will get the returned string as filename. Example if my filename is "ỵ" then IDM will take "4bu5" as filename. My toBase64 function is : Return Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))